# Apache on localhost doesn't recognize a website unless I include the full path to index.html

Tags: apache, webserver

Using MacOS 11.1 Big Sur, I'm developing static websites (ie just a standalone index.html, plus JavaScript and CSS files) on my localhost, with the files accessible under `/Library/Web Server/Documents`.

Unless I include the full path to the website, including the `index.html` section, the website fails to load:

[image]

I can even reproduce this with the standard "it works" file:

[image]

How can I get Apache to check for the presence of the index.html file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this used to work, but I was messing around with MAMP and may have broken something inadvertently

Comment: Could it be because it's `html.en` vs `html`? (I know the .en is supposed to work too for localization, but what if it doesn't?)

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I added a second screenshot to clarify, removing the possible issue with the trailing `.en`

Comment: @StephenLead Undo what you did.  If completely messed up reinstall.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that's the real question - what did I change which broke Apache? I uninstalled MAMP but clearly it's left something broken afterwards. What is missing so that Apache doesn't know to check the index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

Check default settings in httpd.conf - likely you deleted the line that tells Apache what the default file name should be. Check DirectoryIndex listing in your conf file - if missing or edited, add it back in and define index.html as (one of) the default directory file(s).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. httpd.conf lists ```<IfModule dir_module>DirectoryIndex index.php index.html</IfModule>``` so this doesn't appear to be the cause.

Comment: Good first step, however note that this is a conditional statement. This will only work if `dir_module` is enabled - is it? Verify that the `LoadModule dir_module` line in httpd.conf has not been deleted or commented out.

Comment: Full line should read `LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so`

Comment: yep, confirming that the line reads as above without commenting-out. I can workaround this issue for now and I'll probably reinstall this OS sometime, so I'll test it again at that stage. Thanks again for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you do not have any idea about what you broke earlier, you might run into other interesting problems later even if you figure out how to fix this.

I would strongly suggest you reinstall Apache to get back to its original configuration.  As this appears to be a part of the Big Sur installation (and not XCode) you probably need to boot to recovery mode and reinstall Big Sur from there to get the system back in a known state.

You may also be able to just restore the Apache folder from your time machine backup.

In the future I suggest you develop against something more controllable.  These days a good suggestion is using Docker with a suitable Apache container.  You are also strongly suggested to learn and use version control of your code, so you don't lose anything if you suffer from hardware failure.

Comment: ALso when yoiu get unexpected messages from the server look at what the logs say happened

Comment: It's not related to the question, but the OP is already using version control, you can see a .git directory in their screenshot. I don't think I agree about Docker for basic static websites either—now you're running an entire VM under the hood, with all the performance and battery life considerations that entails.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Given what happened here, what other kind of repairable sandbox would you suggest?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion to try reinstalling the OS to restore Apache. But did you really need to be so sarcastic and condecending about it.....

Comment: I wasn’t. You just provided so little information about what you did so it is the only way to be certain.   But I just remembered that you can just restore the whole Apache installation from your time machine backup.